# How to store partial contours point liked the left-hand side in the new vector which type is <vector<vector<Point>> in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, point, contour

I want to store a contour's point at the left-hand side range so I create a new vector `LeftHandSide_contours` to store. However, I compile the following code:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(thresed, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));

vector<vector<Point>> LeftHandSide_contours(contours.size());
int k=0,t=0;
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++) {
            if (contours[i][j].x < src.cols / 2) {     <---- lefthand side frame 
                LeftHandSide_contours[k][t] = contours[i][j];
                t++;
        }
if(contours[i].size!=0) k++;
}
```

and it gives me the following error:

> Line:1740 Expression:vector subscript out of range

Comment: `LeftHandSide_contours[k][t]` is undefined behavior. You have to resize the vector(s) properly first.

Comment: Going through basic C++ [tutorials](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) would most likely answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate space for your vector of vectors prior accessing certain indices:

```
 vector<vector<Point>> LeftHandSide_contours(
    contours.size() ,
    std::vector<Point>(src.cols)
 );
```

That should reserve the memory properly.